# as3 hitTestObject not working after some time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, hittest

so, this is the code in question:

```
function moveObsticle():void
    {
        //move
        var tempObs:MovieClip;
        for(var i:int = obsticles.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            tempObs = obsticles[i];
            tempObs.y = tempObs.y - playerSpeed;
        }

        //test if obsticle is off-stage and set it to remove
        if (tempObs != null && tempObs.y < stage.stageHeight)
        {
            removeObsticle(i);
        }

        //player-obsticle colision
        if (tempObs != null && tempObs.hitTestObject(player))
        {
            gameState = STATE_END;
        }
    }
```

This is one of moveX functions in my code, they all have the same problem.
So this function works perfectly at the begining of the program (game) however after playing a game for mby 30sec or a minute the hitTestObject() just stops working and my game just looses all its gameplay elements.

So the code in question is an if statement at the end of a function, but Im suspecting that mby a for loop might also be a problem, however the if statement above the hitTest one (test if obs is off stage...) does work just fine.

This error is driving me crazy, Ive developed a whole game with that error and now its time to get rid of it, I cant find anybody having a same issue and I have never had that issue before.

code is ran in AIR for Android and the whole thing is developed in Adobe Flash Pro cs6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this code to following:

```
function moveObsticle():void
{
    //move
    var tempObs:MovieClip;
    for(var i:int = obsticles.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempObs = obsticles[i];
        tempObs.y = tempObs.y - playerSpeed;

        //test if obsticle is off-stage and set it to remove
        if (tempObs != null && tempObs.y < stage.stageHeight)
        {
            removeObsticle(i);
            continue;
        }

        //player-obsticle colision
        if (tempObs != null && tempObs.hitTestObject(player))
        {
            gameState = STATE_END;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, your code actually didnt work, the objects would not show on screen anymore (guess they would get removed by the if statement) so I included hitTestObject in for loop but excluded the staheHeight if statement and left it where it was, that resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by changing the code to the following (Idea came from @jfgi):

```
function moveObsticle():void
    {
        //move
        var tempObs:MovieClip;
        for(var i:int = obsticles.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            tempObs = obsticles[i];
            tempObs.y = tempObs.y - playerSpeed;

             //player-obsticle colision
             if (tempObs != null && tempObs.hitTestObject(player))
            {
            gameState = STATE_END;
            }
        }

        //test if obsticle is off-stage and set it to remove
        if (tempObs != null && tempObs.y < stage.stageHeight)
        {
            removeObsticle(i);
        }
    }
```

Thanks @jfgi!

Comment: You can thank jfgi by making sure to select their answer as the correct one.